# React native (expo) app APK not working

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have built an expo (React native) app and in development it is working great, even running perfectly on my android device.  I built an APK and now when i run the apk on the same android device i get my splash screen and then login screen but when i try login i get the following error screen

```
enter code here
```

[image: Error on android device when running apk]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the answer, i had the following code

```
const Loader = ({ }) => {
```

Apparently this works completely fine in dev mode but once you build an APK it breaks the app.  Hope this saves someone else some time